# How to apply circle mask to UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage, calayer

I have read in other questions that in order to apply a circle mask to an UIImageView I should do this:

```
self.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = self.imageView.frame.size.width / 2
self.imageView.clipsToBounds = true
```

But for some reason, when I do that, my image become hidden. When I delete the code to apply the mask, the image is shown perfectly, but nothing appears after applying the mask.

I don't know if it is due to the fact that the UIImageView is inside another UIView, but I don't see why that wouldn't work.

These are the files I'm using to work with the image:

```
import UIKit

class ChatViewController: UIViewController {

    var v: ChatOverview!

    init () {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)

        self.title = "Chat"
        self.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "Chat")
        self.tabBarItem.title = "Chats"
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        v = ChatOverview(
            withName: "Mariano Rajoy",
            andImage: UIImage(named: "Rajoy")!
        )
        self.view.addSubview(v)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            v.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor),
            v.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor),
            v.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200),
            v.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200)
        ])
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        self.v.applyCircleMask()
    }

}
```

And the definition of ChatOverview class:

```
import UIKit

class ChatOverview: UIView {

    var image: UIImage!
    var imageView: UIImageView!

    init (withName name: String, andImage image: UIImage) {
        super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))

        self.image = image

        self.isOpaque = false
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        self.imageView = UIImageView(image: self.image)
        self.imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        self.imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.addSubview(imageView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            self.imageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor),
            self.imageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor),
            self.imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor),
            self.imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor)
        ])
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    func applyCircleMask () {
        self.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = self.imageView.frame.size.width / 2.0
        self.imageView.clipsToBounds = true
    }

}
```

Comment: can you print `ChatOverview`'s frame before `self.v.applyCircleMask()` line is executed?

Comment: I have coded a print and the result gives me this widths and heights: Frame(1463.0, 1463.0) and Layer(1463.0, 1463.0). So same size for both frame and layer of the imageView.

Comment: Try to add `view.layoutIfNeeded()` in the very end of  `viewDidLoad` method

Comment: I tried but that is not working :$

Answer (score 0):

Instead of clipsToBounds, use:

```
self.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Comment: .layer is missing from your code. Can you see the image after removing those 2 lines?

Comment: I have compiled it, and not worked, so I didn't edit my code. Sorry, that must not be the solution.